# How to implement multiple navigation inside a tab?

Tags: java, android

I have two tabs inside MainActivity "FragmentOne" and "Favourites". In "FragmentOne" there is a button clicking on which takes the user to "FragmentTwo". I have put NavHost inside MainActivity and the action is TabOne -> TabTwo.

The button is working fine as well as the tabs. The problem I am having is with The navHost i.e. the button is appearing in both tabs. Also, When I click on the button the contents of "FragmentTwo" is also appearing in both tabs.

I want the button as well as the contents of "FragmentTwo" should appear in the "FragmentOne" tab only.

Here is the code:
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Favourites" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/one_to_favourites"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testproject;

import static androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    tabsAdapter tAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tAdapter = new tabsAdapter(this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(tAdapter);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**tabsAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.testproject;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;
import com.example.testproject.FragmentOne;
import com.example.testproject.FavouritesFragment;

public class tabsAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public tabsAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 1:
                return new FavouritesFragment();

            default:
                return new FragmentOne();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**FragmentOne.Java**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_fragmentOne_to_fragmentTwo);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```